# ElasticSearch edge_ngram not working with single character

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete

Here is my index that I have setup:

```
    $dsl = array(
        'index' => array(
            'analysis' => array(
                'analyzer' => array(
                    'autocomplete' => array(
                        'type' => 'custom',
                        'tokenizer' => 'standard',
                        'filter' => array(
                            'lowercase',
                            'autocomplete_filter'
                        )
                    )
                ),
                'filter' => array(
                    'autocomplete_filter' => array(
                        'type' => 'edge_ngram',
                        'min_gram' => 1,
                        'max_gram' => 20
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

Here are the field properties:

```
public static $optimizedGenericMapping = array(
    "_source" => array(
        "enabled" => true
    ),
    "properties" => array(
        "primaryText" => array(
            "type" => "string",
            "analyzer" => "autocomplete",
            "search_analyzer" => "standard"
        ),
        "secondaryText" => array(
            "type" => "string",
            "analyzer" => "autocomplete",
            "search_analyzer" => "standard"
        ),
        "contentTitle" => array(
            "type" => "string"
        ),
        "contentSubtitle" => array(
            "type" => "string"
        ),
        "contentLocation" => array(
            "type" => "geo_point"
        )
    )
);
```

Here is my search query:

```
        $queryDsl = array(
            'multi_match' => array(
                'query' => $searchQuery,
                'fields' => $primaryOnly ? array('primaryText') : array('primaryText^3', 'secondaryText'),
                'type' => 'phrase_prefix'
            )
        );
```

Now if I search for the following: "San Di", I get results no problem. However, if I search for: "San D", I don't get any results. (search for the city of San Diego)

I know it has to be something simple, but it is driving me crazy, lol.

And I final note, I am using ElasticSearch 5.0. Thanks!

Comment: Did you found a solution to this problem?